# GET a non-input field such as the boostrap datepicker in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, datepicker

I'm trying to send data from the boostrap daterangepicker here: http://www.daterangepicker.com/ via a form submit using GET.

Here is what it's HTMl looks like:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="searchForm" role="form" action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/firstcallres.com/s/AKfycbydvjgkr3nTfA-ZLHe_m1kqavoJCjQhl5bm7Tqelo4/dev" method="get">
  <div class="form-group  col-xs-3" style="margin-left: 10px;">
    <label for="nameInput">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" list="colleagueNames" placeholder="Colleague Name" style=" padding: 1px;" name="user">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group  col-xs-3" style="margin-left:10px;">
    <label for="reportTypeInput">Report Type:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reportTypeInput" placeholder="Report Type" name="reportType">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group  col-xs-4" style="margin-left:10px">
    <label for="dateSelector">Date Range:</label>
    <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;  height: 28px;">
      <i type="text" id="dateSelector" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" name="dateRange"></i>&nbsp;
      <span></span>  <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:25px; margin-left:10px;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="text-align:center;">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript used to initialize:

```
UpdateDatePickerView(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, UpdateDatePickerView);

  function UpdateDatePickerView(start, end) 
  {
      $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  }
```

It's not an `input` and doesn't get sent when submitting a form. How would I go about getting the date pickers data submitted with the form?

Comment: Show the input you initialized the picker on and your javascript code

Comment: I added the entire form and the javascript used to initialize the picker, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a hidden `<input>` element to the `<form>` and populated it with the values from the daterangepicker. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tiomno/7dvL9q6r/2/) as a guide:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="reportrange" id="hd-reportrange"> <!-- check the "reportrange GET value on the server" -->
    <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 28px;">
        <i id="dateSelector" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" name="dateRange"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>
</form> 

<script>
$( '#reportrange' ).daterangepicker(
  {},
  function( start, end, label ) {
    $('#hd-reportrange').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')); //format this values as you which so the server get the info in a straightforward way.
  }
);
</script>
```

Good luck!